# Magento2.2 Getting error after upgrade module

Tags: magento2, module, error

I am using Magento2.2 after upgrade module than comes this error on frontend side if any one idea reply me

```
Class Amasty\ShopbyBase\Helper\PermissionHelper does not exist
```

Comment: Did you check PermissionHelper.php file exists or not inside   Amasty\ShopbyBase?

Comment: I have find out this but not getting this file

Comment: Did you clear your cache and emptied your generated folder?